# Generate an XML listing all files in directory sorted by extension

Tags: php, xml

I need to list all files in a directory (and all subdirectories), and sort them by type. It would be great to include logic sorting by extension (I only have video, image and swf) by type such as:

video - flv. mp4, f4v, avi

image - jpg, png, gif

swf - swf

Comment: This looks very much like a "write my code for me" question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to find all the files in a directory. Then, use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort them using a user-defined function. All that function needs to do is parse the filename for its extension (simple string manipulation with [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)) and return whether one file comes before the other by those extensions.

By then you have a sorted array of files by type/extension, and can loop through it to output your XML.

Once you have some code going, if you run into any problems, you'll have a much better question for StackOverflow (a specific programming problem that has a specific answer).